# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo .vbs o .txt desde vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

Deseo descargar un archivo `.vbs` para que el cliente lo ejecute, pero no puedo hacerlo, según la página de microsoft se hace de la siguiente forma:

```vb
Dim remoteUri As String = Request.Url.Authority
remoteUri = remoteUri + "/Files_Dowload/"
Dim fileName As String = "Script.vbs"
Dim myStringWebResource As String = Nothing
' Create a new WebClient instance.
Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()
' Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename. Because DownloadFile 
'requires a fully qualified resource name, concatenate the domain with the Web resource file name.
 myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName
 Console.WriteLine("Downloading File ""{0}"" from ""{1}"" ......." + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Cr, fileName, myStringWebResource)
 ' The DownloadFile() method downloads the Web resource and saves it into the current file-system folder.
 myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, fileName) '<--- Aquí me aparece el error
 Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded file ""{0}"" from ""{1}""", fileName, myStringWebResource)
```

Pero desde mi página me genera el siguiente error

> ```
> Se detectó System.Net.WebException
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message=Excepción durante una solicitud WebClient.
>   Source=System
>   StackTrace:
>        en System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>        en System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(String address, String fileName)
>        en PanelSeguridad.HuellasAjax.Cargar() en D:\VERSIONAMIENTO_GITHUB\SASIF_PERSONAS\PanelSeguridad\Huellas\Creacion\HuellasAjax.aspx.vb:línea
> 96
>   InnerException: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
>        HResult=-2147024891
>        Message=Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Script.vbs'.
>        Source=mscorlib
>        StackTrace:
>             en System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>             en System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare
> share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
> secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath,
> Boolean checkHost)
>             en System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>             en System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)
>        InnerException:
> ```

La verdad es la primera vez que quiero hacer una descarga con este metodo, no sé si puedan ayudarme o una mejor manera de hacerlo, necesito que se descargue, no que el navegador lo abra :/y lo muestre como un archivo de texto

Comment: parece un error de falta de permisos de escritura dentro de IIS... te fijaste que la aplicacion pueda escribir?

Comment: Si, dí todos los permisos a todos los usuarios y nada :/

Comment: ese archivo no existe ahi? probaste guardarlo con otro nombre?

Comment: Es que eso es exactamente lo que no sé hacer, es decir, no sé qué proceso se debe hacer para descargar un archivo... :(

Comment: el segundo parametro del metodo downloadfile es el nombre del archivo de destino. probaste con el codigo de ejemplo que efectivamente bajara algun archivo?

Comment: y si necesitas mas ayuda me encuentras en el chat.

Comment: No, eso es lo que no sé, estoy intentando probarlo, pero no puedo, no sé cómo :/ he intentdao con `Response.Writefile` y otro que es como tranferfile o algo así pero ninguno funciona, los escriben en la consola y en la url y no descargan nada :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera utilizando JS

```
function descargar (url_descarga, name_descarga){

    var a = document.createElement('a');

                if (typeof a.download != "undefined") {
                    var save = document.createElement('a');
                    save.href = url_descarga
                    save.target = '_blank';
                    save.download = name_descarga || 'archivo.dat';
                    var clicEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
                        'view': window,
                        'bubbles': true,
                        'cancelable': true
                    });
                    save.dispatchEvent(clicEvent);
                    (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
                }
                else {
                    Mensaje_General("Navegador no Soportado", "El navegador actual no soporta la sentencia usada para la transferencia del archivo, deberá ejecutar la aplicación usted mismo.", "E");
                }
    }
```

donde la `url_descarga` es la dirección de donde se traerá el archivo, y `name_descarga` es el nombre (deben agregar la extensión) con que se descargará el archivo.

Comment: ya que estas por aca de vez en cuando no te aceptas tu respuesta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Por si quieres usar otra alternativa para la descarga del archivo sin necesidad de usar JS

```
Dim Data As String
Dim Address As String = "http://myftp.com/file.vba"
Dim Client1 As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Client1.OpenRead(address))
Data = reader.ReadToEnd
client1.Dispose()
MsgBox(Data)
```